# Magento 2 API - change returning JSON key

Tags: magento2.3.1

I have created custom API with Magento that will be consumed by 3rd party system, which expect fix formate of API response. I have created API data interface and I could able to get formate what they need, but facing problem with JSON associated that API returns,

Magento by default changing getter method name into SnakeCase, i.e I have

```
public function getInvoiceUrl();
```

this will return

```
{
  "invoice_url": "string"
}
```

But my expected output is UpperCamelCase like

```
{
  "InvoiceUrl": "string"
}
```

how can I achieve this with API data interface??

As returning API data with array will return response like,

```
[{
    "InvoiceUrl": "string"
}]
```

Comment: can you include the code with the exact format of the response

Comment: Hey @fmsthird, I have shared the scenario, please let me know what part of code you require..?

Comment: I have found the place where Magento is doing this magic, but overwriting code feature doesn't seems any solution

Comment: There is not strait forward way to achieve, I have to go with customization of core lib file and finally got the solution  :)